# Use Theme/Skin or CSS in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, css

I am working on a website which is using Skin templates everywhere in the page. Because of this all the controls, even labels, are server controls. I was wondering if it is worth changing at least labels to HTML controls and create CSS for them. Is there any advantage of using Skin over CSS?

Answer (score 1):

I would stick with all CSS or all theme/skins. The reason is that when they are used together it's ambiguous which is actually going to be displayed to the user if both attempt to modify the same things. Also adding another language to work with for no real reason is a bad idea, it's unneeded complexity. There is not going to be any significant difference in performance between having HTML controls or server controls for labels, and there is no difference between having CSS that works or themes/skins that work.

remember KISS(keep it simple stupid) and "if it aint broke don't fix it", you are attempting to violate both.